# Sencha 2 - Call functions within a view

Tags: sencha-touch-2

This is a snippet from my view inside the config object:

```
xtype: 'fieldset',
cls:   'loginFormText',
items:[
    {
        xtype: 'timepickerfield',
        label: 'Start',
        value: this.fromTime(),
        name:  'fromTime'
    },{
        xtype: 'timepickerfield',
        label: 'End',
        value: this.toTime(),
        name:  'toTime'
    }
]
```

And in bottom of the view I have the following functions:

```
fromTime: function(){
    var fromDate = new Date();
    fromDate.setHours(12);
},
toTime: function(){
    var toDate = new Date();
    toDate.setHours(18);
}
```

But the way I try to call them with "this.fromTime()" and "this.toTime()" doesnt work, how do I call them?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it. At creation time *this* refers to a global Window object, not at Sencha class. To workaround you have to do it in the initialize() function. Eg. this should work...

```
Ext.define (MyApp.view.CoolView, {
    xtype: 'coolview',
    config: {
        layout: 'fit'
    },

    initialize: function () {

      var items = {
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        cls:   'loginFormText',
        items:[
            {
                xtype: 'timepickerfield',
                label: 'Start',
                value: this.fromTime(),
                name:  'fromTime'
            },{
                xtype: 'timepickerfield',
                label: 'End',
                value: this.toTime(),
                name:  'toTime'
            }
        ]
      }
      this.setItems(items);
    },

    fromTime: function(){
        var fromDate = new Date();
        fromDate.setHours(12);
        return fromDate;
    },
    toTime: function(){
        var toDate = new Date();
        toDate.setHours(18);
        return toDate;
    }
})
```

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: Does it work ? Because it looks like to me that  toTime and fromTime don't return anything.